# How to stop DIVS from colliding when page resized (footer)?

Tags: html, css

How to stop divs from colliding when page is resized (footer)? I had a look online and I couldn't quite find what I was looking for - so apologies if this question has already been answered.

I'm in the middle of building a footer and I wanted to know how do I stop the four  containing product, company, support, support from colliding with each other when the page is resized.

I assume I need to put min-width in there somewhere, is it best to create a new div with the 4 nested divs and apply a min-width? Would this work if not is there a better way?

I would also like to keep the divs evenly spaced out in the center of the page.

HTML:

```
<footer>
<div id="insidefooterfixone">
     <h5>Product</h5> 
    <ul>
        <li>Domains</li>
        <li>Hosting</li>
        <li>Server</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="insidefooterfixtwo">
     <h5>Company</h5> 
    <ul>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>Our Customers</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Terms of Service</li>
        <li>Privacy Policy</li>
        <li>Security</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="insidefooterfixthree">
     <h5>Support</h5> 
    <ul>
        <li>Help Documents</li>
        <li>API Documents</li>
        <li>Tutorials</li>
        <li>FAQ - Database</li>
        <li>System Status</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="insidefooterfixfour">
     <h5>Support</h5> 
    <ul>
        <li>helpdesk@data.co.uk</li>
        <li>01223 000000</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="disclaimerfix">
    <p>2002-2014 Dataconnectivity Ltd.</p>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background-color: #3a3a3a;
list-style: none;
height: 450px;  
float: left;}

#insidefooterfixone h5, #insidefooterfixtwo h5, #insidefooterfixthree h5, #insidefooterfixfour h5 {
text-align:left;
margin-bottom: 0;
color:#FFFFFF;  }

#insidefooterfixone li, #insidefooterfixtwo li, #insidefooterfixthree li,   #insidefooterfixfour li {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0;
color: #C9C9C9; }

#insidefooterfixone ul, #insidefooterfixtwo ul, #insidefooterfixthree ul,     #insidefooterfixfour ul{
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0;
color: #C9C9C9; }

#insidefooterfixone {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 31.3%;
width: 150px;    }

#insidefooterfixtwo {
position: relative;
top: -115px;
left: 39.667%;
width: 150px;   }

#insidefooterfixthree {
position: relative;
top: -298px;
left: 48%;
width: 150px;    }

#insidefooterfixfour {
position: relative;
top: -458px;
left: 56.33%;
width: 150px;}
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Lgdx/

Thanks.

P.S Don't worry about 4 divs aligning (all seems to change when transferred onto another application)

Comment: Check this [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Lgdx/2/). It does solves your purpose but I've done it using Bootstrap 3 css framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your divs are overlapping is because your using percent to position them.
I would recomend not using percentage at all when it comes to positioning the divs and instead use `display: inline-block;` to align your columns like so:

**CSS**

```
.column{
    max-width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding:0 10px;
}
```

Note that I removed all the `left` and `top`positioning in the fiddle. I also added a class to the footer columns called `column`.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lgdx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using percentage to align the divs and pixels for the width. You shouldn't do that because if the screen shrinks, the width of the divs won't shrink with it.

Either position the divs using pixels, or have the width in percentages too.